# Create css grid with fix numbers of rows and n number of columns?

Tags: css, grid, row

html

```
html 
<div class='container'>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
    <div>11</div>
</div>
```

I want divide child div tags into 3 rows and any number of columns

I tried using display: grid property but I am unable to make fix number rows.

Comment: take the time to read all the duplicate. The linked question is not the same but all the possible solutions are listed there